# Which HOST+PORT to use for NodeJS app on OpenShift?

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, openshift, port

I can't get my NodeJS-app working on OpenShift. Everywhere it is written to use the env. variables

```
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT
OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP
```

but they are not present in my pod. If I just listen on some other IP and PORT (e.g. on port 3000 of 127.0.0.1), the app successfully deploys but does not receive any requests (and also cannot be reached from the exposed address). Output of the printenv command in the terminal of my pod running the NodeJS app is in the attached pictures (sorry, did not figure out how to copy text from the web terminal).

[Output of printenv, 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlFr3.png)

[Output of printenv, 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mphZj.png)

All variables having something to do with NODEJS_* indicate the IP 172.30.72.54, and PORT 8080. However, if I use these, I get a "listen EADDRNOTAVAIL" error.

Btw, also the OpenShift CLI indicates the same IP and PORT:

```
$ oc get services
NAME      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
mongodb   ClusterIP   172.30.20.188   <none>        27017/TCP   2d
nodejs    ClusterIP   172.30.72.54    <none>        8080/TCP    2d
```

So by now, I don't have any clue and can't find any information about what IP and PORT to use for my NodeJS app. Thanks for any help!

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: You are reading docs for OpenShift V2, not V3. In V3 with OpenShift S2I builder you should listen on port 8080 and use a listener IP of 0.0.0.0. See https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-nodejs-container/tree/master/8 and example at https://github.com/sclorg/nodejs-ex/blob/master/server.js#L11

Comment: BTW, when you then expose your web application via a route, external to the cluster it would be standard HTTP port and whatever generated hostname for site is. You wouldn't use internal IP:PORT to access from outside.

Comment: Rob: I know. Just didn't want to spend half an hour to type in those lines for a question that's probably answered quickly. Graham: thanks, that's all I needed to know. Works fine now. I'm using `if(process.env.OPENSHIFT_BUILD_NAME)` to check whether I'm on OpenShift or not.